# Create multiple PDFs at the same time

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, pdf-generation

I want to create Multiple PDFS at the same time.But every the documents always overwrite.
The first one is ok but afterwards the 2nd one and the 3rd one the text is overwriting.

```
<?php

    try {
        $pdf = new My_Pdf();

        $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
        $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES);
        $page->setFont($font, 11);
        $data = Model_DefendantsBanksMapper::getInstance()->getForPDF($values[0]['id']);

        foreach ($data as $k => $defendant) {
                           $pdf->drawText($page, $defendant, 85, 660);


            $pdf->pages[] = $page;
            $pdf->save('pdf/Bank_Supoena_' . $values[0]['id'] . '_' . $k . '.pdf');
        }


    } catch (Zend_Pdf_Exception $e) {
        die('PDF error: ' . $e->getMessage());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die('Application error: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

?>
```

Comment: $pdf->save(path), check if path is same always..take in a variable and keep echoing or save in log

Comment: And you should reset the pages of your pdf unless you want every following pdfs to have the previous pages + a new one. If not you should move the instantiation of your pdf variable into the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it. thanks. the creation of the pdf should have been in the foreach